# Logstash JDBC Input Plugin - DB2

Tags: db2, logstash-jdbc

I am trying to connect to DB2 database on Mainframe from my local machine. I am using JDBC input plugin. It seems the jdbc driver license file is not getting loaded. Can someone please tell me how can I load the db2jcc_license_cisuz-1.4.2.jar file.

I am using logstash version 6.2.2

I am able to connect to DB2 using the same license file from other Java applications.

My config file is as follows:

```
input {
    beats {
        port => 5044
    }
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:db2://XX.XX.XX.XX:1304/DB91"
        jdbc_user => "username"
        jdbc_password => "password"
        jdbc_driver_library => "C:\logstash-6.2.2\logstash-6.2.2\vendor\jruby\lib\jdbc\db2jcc-1.4.2.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
        statement => "SELECT * from DBTPS29.NPSXTEI"
    }
}
output {
    stdout {codec => json_lines}
}
```

log file :

```
[2018-08-21T11:19:24,334][ERROR][logstash.inputs.jdbc ] Unable to connect to database. Tried 1 times {:error_message=>"Java::ComIbmDb2JccAm::SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][t4][10509][13454][3.61.96] Connection to the data server failed. The IBM Data Server for JDBC and SQLJ license was invalid \r\nor was not activated for the DB2 for z/OS subsystem. If you are connecting directly to \r\nthe data server and using DB2 Connect Unlimited Edition for System z, perform the \r\nactivation step by running the activation program in the license activation kit. \r\nIf you are using any other edition of DB2 Connect, obtain the license file, \r\ndb2jcc_license_cisuz.jar, from the license activation kit, and follow the installation \r\ndirections to include the license file in the class path. ERRORCODE=-4230, SQLSTATE=42968"}
[2018-08-21T11:19:24,338][ERROR][logstash.pipeline ] A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
Pipeline_id:main
Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc jdbc_connection_string=>"jdbc:db2://xx.xx.xx.xx:1304/DB91", jdbc_user=>"username", jdbc_password=>, jdbc_driver_library=>"C:\logstash-6.2.2\logstash-6.2.2\vendor\jruby\lib\jdbc\db2jcc-1.4.2.jar", jdbc_driver_class=>"com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver", statement=>"SELECT * from DBTPS29.NPSXTEI", id=>"f63556360d1928aaaf73cf6a06df9ec2cc1f8252c016d62da5830f446521927e", enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Plain id=>"plain_bad95943-2146-4d84-a312-0be5db02acef", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, jdbc_paging_enabled=>false, jdbc_page_size=>100000, jdbc_validate_connection=>false, jdbc_validation_timeout=>3600, jdbc_pool_timeout=>5, sql_log_level=>"info", connection_retry_attempts=>1, connection_retry_attempts_wait_time=>0.5, parameters=>{"sql_last_value"=>1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC}, last_run_metadata_path=>"C:\Users\vipul.parikh/.logstash_jdbc_last_run", use_column_value=>false, tracking_column_type=>"numeric", clean_run=>false, record_last_run=>true, lowercase_column_names=>true>
Error: Java::ComIbmDb2JccAm::SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][t4][10509][13454][3.61.96] Connection to the data server failed. The IBM Data Server for JDBC and SQLJ license was invalid
or was not activated for the DB2 for z/OS subsystem. If you are connecting directly to
the data server and using DB2 Connect Unlimited Edition for System z, perform the
activation step by running the activation program in the license activation kit.
If you are using any other edition of DB2 Connect, obtain the license file,
db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar, from the license activation kit, and follow the installation
directions to include the license file in the class path. ERRORCODE=-4230, SQLSTATE=42968
Exception: Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError
Stack: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(com/ibm/db2/jcc/am/ed.java:676)
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(com/ibm/db2/jcc/am/ed.java:60)
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(com/ibm/db2/jcc/am/ed.java:120)
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.jb.Qb(com/ibm/db2/jcc/am/jb.java:4339)
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.jb.b(com/ibm/db2/jcc/am/jb.java:4248)
com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(com/ibm/db2/jcc/t4/b.java:537)
com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(com/ibm/db2/jcc/t4/b.java:366)
com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.(com/ibm/db2/jcc/t4/b.java:305)
com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(com/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource.java:214)
com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(com/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2Driver.java:460)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java/lang/reflect/Method.java:498)
org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(org/jruby/javasupport/JavaMethod.java:468)
org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(org/jruby/javasupport/JavaMethod.java:326)
C_3a_.logstash_minus_6_dot_2_dot_2.logstash_minus_6_dot_2_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.sequel_minus_5_dot_4_dot_0.lib.sequel.adapters.jdbc.connect(C:/logstash-6.2.2/logstash-6.2.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.4.0/lib/sequel/adapters/jdbc.rb:203)
C_3a_.logstash_minus_6_dot_2_dot_2.logstash_minus_6_dot_2_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.sequel_minus_5_dot_4_dot_0.lib.sequel.connection_pool.make_new(C:/logstash-6.2.2/logstash-6.2.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.4.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool.rb:126)
C_3a_.logstash_minus_6_dot_2_dot_2.logstash_minus_6_dot_2_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.sequel_minus_5_dot_4_dot_0.lib.sequel.connection_pool.threaded.assign_connection(C:/logstash-6.2.2/logstash-6.2.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.4.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:192)
C_3a_.logstash_minus_6_dot_2_dot_2.logstash_minus_6_dot_2_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.sequel_minus_5_dot_4_dot_0.lib.sequel.connection_pool.threaded.acquire(C:/logstash-6.2.2/logstash-6.2.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.4.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:133)
C_3a_.logstash_minus_6_dot_2_dot_2.logstash_minus_6_dot_2_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.sequel_minus_5_dot_4_dot_0.lib.sequel.connection_pool.threaded.hold(C:/logstash-6.2.2/logstash-6.2.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.4.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:90)
C_3a_.logstash_minus_6_dot_2_dot_2.logstash_minus_6_dot_2_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.sequel_minus_5_dot_4_dot_0.lib.sequel.database.connecting.synchronize(C:/logstash-6.2.2/logstash-6.2.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.4.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:269)


`C_3a_.logstash_minus_6_dot_2_dot_2.logstash_minus_6_dot_2_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.sequel_minus_5_dot_4_dot_0.lib.sequel.database.connecting.test_connection(C:/logstash-6.2.2/logstash-6.2.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.4.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:279)
    C_3a_.logstash_minus_6_dot_2_dot_2.logstash_minus_6_dot_2_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.sequel_minus_5_dot_4_dot_0.lib.sequel.database.connecting.connect(C:/logstash-6.2.2/logstash-6.2.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.4.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:58)

   C_3a_.logstash_minus_6_dot_2_dot_2.logstash_minus_6_dot_2_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.sequel_minus_5_dot_4_dot_0.lib.sequel.core.connect(C:/logstash-`
```

Answer (score 0):

The license file name should be `db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar` and it should be in the same directory location as the db2jcc.jar or db2jcc4.jar.  If these two are already verified to be true, then talk with your Z/OS DB2 DBA and ensure that the activation step has been performed for `...by running the activation program in the license activation kit`.  Your Z/OS DB2 DBA should know what that means and how to do it.